# Firebase list isn't showing at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-services

Angular is saying that my function is not working, however, in VS Code, it isn't showing anything wrong. However, at runtime it can't display my list of items from the database?

Using Angular 8 and Firebase

canvas-list-component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCanvasList();
  }

  getCanvasList() {
    this.canvasService.getCanvasList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(canvases => {
      this.canvases = canvases;
    });
  }
```

CanvasSerivce.ts

```
 canvasRef: AngularFireList<Canvas> = null;
 ...
 getCanvasList(): AngularFireList<Canvas> {
    return this.canvasRef;
  }
```

Produces this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.canvasService.getCanvasList is not a function
    at CanvasListComponent.getCanvasList (canvas-list.component.ts:21)
    at CanvasListComponent.ngOnInit (canvas-list.component.ts:17)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:23869)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:34427)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:34366)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:35388)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:35331)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CanvasListComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:35319)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:34331)
```

I expect the output of this to retrieve a list of items from my realtime database

Comment: you are just returning `null`, so it doesn't fetch anything, but that is beside the error. Just wanted to point that out. Anyway, there is not enough code to be a [mcve], so it's hard to tell what's wrong.